# How to make sweet-tasting noodles?

Tags: flavor, dough, noodles, texture

I've never made noodle dough before, and I want to try it today. However, I'd like to make the noodles more sweet.

Is the base ingredient ratio for making the noodle dough one egg per 100g flour?

How can I make it sweeter? Would I just add sugar or is there a better ingredient to add that will not change the texture of the noodles?

Will adding butter and milk change the texture of the noodle?

Comment: I want to start cooking now, no answers yet? I guess I'll have to find out myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Butter and milk will add fat and water which will definitely change the consistency of the dough. You will have to adjust the ratios if you add them (surely more flour if you add milk).

If you want sweet noodles my best bet would be to add sugar, although I wouldn't do sweet egg noodles... maybe sweet rice noodles?

Why don't you just do plain noodles and then make a sweet condiment instead?

Comment: Tried it now, I added sugar only... it didn't taste very good. I guess you're right, a sweet condiment or so might be a better idea. However, sweet rice noodles sounds really tasty :)

Comment: Do I need the same amount of flour for normal noodles and rice noodles? And how long does it take until they're cooked?

Comment: hmmmm... never made rice noodle in my life sorry! :) Cooking is very fast for fresh pasta, less than 3-4 minutes (depending on the thickness). Generally rice noodle even cook faster.

Comment: I don't know if the fat in milk will change the texture too much. Spätzle are often made with milk or cheese as the liquid. If you want to add milk to egg noodles, you can either use more liquid (making them spätle-like), or substitute milk instead of egg, which won't increase the fat content much.

Comment: @rumtscho: hmmmm... I think Spätzle have a pretty different texture than egg noodles, don't you think (at least the ones I have eaten, I don't know how original they were though)?

Comment: Yes, their texture is different. But my point is that they are a type of noodles with fat, and they don't fall apart or anything when boiled. It is obvious that the more the ratio of liquid to flour is changed by the addition of milk, the more the texture will be changed - but fat isn't the reason.

Comment: @rumtscho: you're right, I'll remove that from the answer

Comment: I swear I'll get killed for suggesting german/austrian things here one day ... well, if we want sweet noodles, we cook them in sugar and milk (you could use soymilk or almond milk) instead of water (adding more milk when needed and letting it absorb), the pasta absorbs plenty of the mixture. Known as a simple children's dish (Milchnudeln), but there are also more evolved forms like Ödenburger Auflauf, an old-school comfort food that combines sweet noodles with poppyseed filling,